get reference of case class from it's fully qualified name to be used to convert dataframe to dataset
I have a fully qualified name of case classes. For my use case at runtime I need to get the reference of case class to be used to convert dataframe to dataset.
eg.

I have the FQN as: com.org.common.Field

I want to perform something like dataframe.as[Field]


But this reference is not working.
I have done something like
  val df = Seq(
    ("1", "2")
  ).toDF("name", "dataType")


  val fqn: String = "com.org.common.Field$"
  val clazz = Class.forName(fqn)

  val typedDf = df.as(Encoders.bean(clazz))

  typedDf.show()
  typedDf.printSchema()

Output is
+----+--------+
|name|dataType|
+----+--------+
|   1|       2|
+----+--------+

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dataType: string (nullable = true)

and the case class is:
case class Field(name: String, dataType: Int)


It seems like you are trying to mix concepts.  Bean encoders fully use the java bean reflection standard to create/read classes.  Product encoders are used for case classes.
See here: Apache Spark docs - creating datasets for how this works.
Your Field type has Int for dataType but your Seq has string:
import spark.implicits._ // or whatever your session variable name is
val ds = Seq(Field("1",2)).toDS
ds.show
ds.printSchema

With a Seq of the correct type the import will allow toDS and encoders to be derived based on Field.  If you already have a DataFrame (Dataset[Row]) with the correct types then:
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(
    ("1", 2)
  ).toDF("name", "dataType")
val ds = df.as[Field]

will work.

I agree.
I have a specific use case where i have the list of fully qualified name and want to get the type of each one to be used to convert dataframe to dataset.

I assumed that was a phrasing issue, that's just not making much sense.  You aren't converting anything in that case, please update your question to explain what you are actually needing to do or hoping to achieve with that.
